# My python script runs indefinitely in the background only if i redirect the output to a file, why is this?

Tags: linux, python, redirection

So I have a python script which is programmed to run indefinitely. It prints a small string initially, but then just runs pretty much silently. I found that it runs about a day if I initiate it like so:

```
python main.py &
```

However, it runs for however long i want when i do this:

```
python main.py > /dev/null &
```

I can't really identify why this should happen. Am I running things wrongly?

Comment: "pretty much silently" is how many bytes per hour (how long to fill a 4K buffer)? Does the script exit or hang? How do you start it exactly? systemd service? in a terminal?

Comment: @xenoid to answer your questions... it outputs a line: "script started" and then stays silent (i thought that it might fill the buffer). I start the script in terminal. The script is simply not running at the end even though it is a relatively simple while 1: (two threads)

Comment: just to elaborate on the silence of the script: when i piped the output to a file, it resulted in a 22byte file after almost a week...